Get genesis hash in program
Is it possible to retrieve the genesis hash of the cluster from a Solana program?
I don't see it a available in any of the SysVars.

The genesis hash for a cluster is not exposed to programs. If you want to know which chain you're on, you can build some constant into your program, which varies based on the deployment cluster, ie:
#[cfg(feature = "mainnet-beta")]
const CHAIN: u64 = 0;
#[cfg(feature = "devnet")]
const CHAIN: u64 = 1;
#[cfg(feature = "testnet")]
const CHAIN: u64 = 2;

And then build properly with:
cargo build-sbf --features devnet


This works for Solana clusters, but doesn't necessarily scale to multiple SVMs.

I think compiler directives are an anti-pattern here, and a sysvar would be more helpful. Otherwise it places a larger burden on CI management.

it's true that it doesn't scale to more clusters -- feel free to propose a new sysvar! While you're at it, you might want to consider how a wallet / user can identify the cluster targeted by a transaction. One of our concerns when there are multiple clusters is how a wallet can know the outcome of a transaction by looking at it. We might need to add a new transaction version that contains something like a chain id or the genesis hash
